# List selection issue while using CustomListItem and StandardListItem inside the List with includeItemInSelection

Tags: sapui5

I have the following view, which has **List** and I have set **includeItemInSelection** property to **true**. And there I have attached to **selectionChange** event also.

```
<mvc:View 
    controllerName="com.naveen.test.list.controller.List"
    xmlns="sap.m" 
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    height="100%">
    <List 
        selectionChange="onSelectionChange" 
        includeItemInSelection = "true"
        mode = "MultiSelect"
        items="{
            path: '/data',
            factory: '.listItemFactory'
        }">
    </List>
</mvc:View>
```

Mainly the list items are going to be instantiated via factory method **listItemFactory** as follows in the controller.

```
    listItemFactory : function(sId, oContext) {
        var each = oContext.getObject();
        var listItem = null;
        if( each.type === 'Group' ) {
            var childList = new List({
                includeItemInSelection : true,
                selectionChange : jQuery.proxy(this.onSelectionChange,this),
                mode : "MultiSelect"
            });
            childList.bindItems({
                path : 'childData',
                factory : jQuery.proxy(this._childListFactory, this)
            });
            listItem = new CustomListItem({
                selected : '{selected}',
                content : [childList]
            });
        } else {
            listItem = this._childListFactory(sId, oContext);
        }
        return listItem;
    },
    _childListFactory : function(sId, oContext){
        return new StandardListItem({
            title : '{name}',
            selected : '{selected}'
        });
    },
    onSelectionChange : function(oEvent) {
        console.log(oEvent);
    }
```

And the json data for this as follows.

```
{  
   "data":[  
    {
        "id" : "1",
        "name" : "Name1",
        "selected" : true,
        "type" : "Normal",
        "childData" : []
    },
    {
        "id" : "2",
        "name" : "Name2",
        "selected" : false,
        "type" : "Normal",
        "childData" : []
    },
    {  
        "id":"LAYER15",
        "name":"Name3",
        "selected":true,
        "type":"Group",
        "childData" : [  
            {
                "id":"3-1",
                "name":"Name3-1",
                "selected":true
            },
            {  
                "id":"3-2",
                "name":"Name3-2",
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "id":"3-3",
                "name":"Name3-3",
                "selected":true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

**But When we click on the child list item it will fire the event for that child list item also and for the Parent list item also.** How to stop the parent event for that one item.

FYI, Click on the item which has the title **Name3-2.**
See the console there will be two logs.

Answer (score 1):

try using **preventDefault()** function of jQuery.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: First of all I Thank you. I tried with **preventDefault** and **cancelBubble**. But in the List control of ui5 only **swipe** event can be cancellable not **selectionChange** event.